# Using Java stream to get map containing a key and the number of occurrences of that key from a List

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List<Map.Entry<Double, Boolean>>` feature.

I would like to count the number of occurrences of the possible values of `Boolean` in the list.

The current attempt I have made is

```
Map<Boolean, List<Map.Entry<Double, Boolean>>> classes = 
    feature.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Instead of the `Map<Boolean, List<Map.Entity<Double, Boolean>` I would like a `Map<Boolean, Integer>` where the integer is the number of occurances.

I have tried

```
Map<Boolean, List<Map.Entry<Double, Boolean>>> classes = 
    feature.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, List::size));
```

But this throws a no suitable method function.

I am new to the stream API so any help achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you call `occurrences of the possible values of Boolean`, how many true, and how many false?

Comment: @AnthonyRaymond yeah that's what I mean, could also replace Boolean with String or something and get all the occurrences of "Hello" and "World" if the appear in the map for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers work perfectly, but if you insist on getting a `Map<Boolean,Integer>` you need this:

```
Map<Boolean,Integer> result = feature.stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Function.identity(), 
                Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.counting(), Long::intValue)));
```

Comment: The Integer isn't necessary over a Long :) but since you're the only one to answer the question as I asked it I'm accepting yours

Answer (score 1):

You can use *map* function to get list of Booleans and *groupingBy* it:

```
Map<Boolean, Long> collect = feature.stream()
                .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a result of `Map<Boolean, Long>`:

```
List<Map.Entry<Double, Boolean>> feature = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Boolean, Long> result = feature
        .stream()
        .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                 Collectors.counting()));
```

Comment: Or `Collectors.partitioningBy()`.